# What algorithm finds the diameter of an unrooted non-binary tree?

Tags: computer-science, graph-theory

Given an undirected unrooted non binary tree we must find one of the diameters of said tree in the shortest running time possible without using recursive methods.

I've seen many different answers and would like clarity on which is correct. When given an undirected unrooted non binary tree, can you run a BFS on any vertex A to get the furthest vertex B from that, then run BFS on that B node which will result in the diameter between B and the resulting C?

Beyond this, if this is indeed correct what is the time complexity? I have seen O(E) and O(E+V)

Comment: About the complexity: in a tree, `E = V-1`, so ultimately `O(V) = O(E) = O(V+E)`

Answer (score 0):

> I've seen many different answers and would like clarity on which is correct. When given an undirected unrooted non binary tree, can you run a BFS on any vertex A to get the furthest vertex B from that, then run BFS on that B node which will result in the diameter between B and the resulting C?

Yes, this algorithm is correct, `d(B, C)` is then the diameter of the tree. You can find more informations about this algorithm (and why it works) on [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22855/algorithm-to-find-diameter-of-a-tree-using-bfs-dfs-why-does-it-work).

> Beyond this, if this is indeed correct what is the time complexity? I have seen O(E) and O(E+V)

You're running a BFS on the tree twice. Each BFS has a time complexity of `O(V)` since each vertex is visited exactly once.
In a tree, the equality `E = V-1` is always verified, so for any algorithm running on a tree, `O(V) = O(E) = O(E + V)`, so both notation are correct. `O(V)` is better IMHO, for the sake of simplicity and clarity.